# C++ creating object based on condition

Tags: c++

I create an object based on a command line option.

In C++

```
Capture *cc = NULL;
if ( argv[2] == "capture" )
  cc = new Capture(<some args>);
```

Now to use this at different parts of the code, should i create a CaptureStub that contains dummy functions so that null pointer is never accessed. Or is there an easier way?

Thanks

Comment: -1. Post code that atleast should compile so that we don't waste time correcting syntax.

Comment: I'm assuming there's a typo here and you meant Capture* cc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> should i create a CaptureStub that contains dummy functions

You mean the [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)? Yes that would be fine.

> Or is there an easier way?

I'm not sure there's an easier way (Null object patterns is a pretty good way) but a very idiomatic way is to check for NULL

```
 if (cc != NULL)
 {
    // do something with cc
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your `if` condition will never be true, since the `==` compares the address of the string literal `capture` to the second command line argument.  You'll want to change it to something like `strcmp("capture", argv[2] == 0)` or `(string("capture") == string(argv[2]))`.

Second, I think we need to think through the semantics of what you want.  What is the desired behavior if the 'capture' option is not specified?  Do noithing?  If not, then, as @Doug T. mentions, the Null Object pattern is a good choice, rather than sprinkling your code with comparisons to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Capture cc = NULL;
```

Ugh, that's not a pointer right there. If it compiles it's because the Capture class has an implicit constructor that accepts an int or pointer, or has an `operator=`.

To correct this use

```
Capture* cc = NULL;
```

After that, you should structure your code in a way that you only use the object if it is initialized. If it's not possible, then check every time before you do so.